In Cloudinary, how to track eager transformation using batch_id?
In Cloudinary, I'm encountering an issue with eager transformation. When I uploaded a file, I received the following response:
{batch_id=<GENERARED_BATCH_ID>, type=upload, status=pending}.
However, my notification URL isn't being triggered, but this is only happening for a single file. I tried to perform an eager transform for the same file multiple times.
I'm able to eager transform other files successfully, and their notification URLs are triggered as expected.
Please advise me on how to trace the issue using the batch_id to understand why the notification URL isn't getting triggered for this particular file.
Any help would be appreciated.

Are you sure the notification URL isn't being triggered? It may be that you're receiving details of an error that occurred during the processing but were expecting a successful response, causing an error in your webhook-handling code. If so, the notification may explain the error. If not, I recommend opening a support request with the specific details of the upload so it can be checked by the Support team at Cloudinary

I have put logger statements so yes I am sure that notification URL is not being triggered in some cases. I am not seeing any reference to track transformation using batch_id on their official documentation. Last option will be create a support ticket.

The batch_id is just for reference and can't be used later to retrieve the asset details. You can receive the asset details via the webhook notification or by checking the search/Admin API methods for the public_id value you provided with the upload, if applicable. However, only the webhook can send you error details if the transformations failed, and retrieving the asset details via the API will only show you the updated metadata if the transformation was successful. If you requested a notification and didn't receive it, please contact support with the specifics so it can be investigated.

@Igy Thanks for the explanation. I received an error response for all the pending ones after an hour. Request R1 made at time T1 for a smaller file got processed later whereas Request R2 made at time T2 for a bigger size file was processed immediately. Important thing here is my notification URL triggered for all the transformation call.
